# iPadOS stage manager: how to use external display only or as main display

Tags: ipados, stage-manager

The purpose is to use M1 iPadAir as a desktop computer, so it is not very easy to access the built in screen at any time.

Mirror display works well but there are wasted black areas on the left and right of the monitor, also the 4K resolution (or possibly 6~8K) is not fully utilized since iPad will use the native resolution of the built in display in mirror mode.

But non-mirror mode will make the built in screen the main display, so in many cases you need to see the built in screen to operate, e.g. the app icons are all on the built in screen.

Either using external display only or using it as the main display is OK. but both seem not to be possible for the current version (16.7.1)?